# Generating TypeScript declarations for re-exported JS functions in a Node.js module

Tags: node.js, typescript, jsdoc, auto-generate, typescript-declarations

I am trying to emit declarations for types and functions annotated with JSDoc. Those are useful for TypeScript users and generating them from JSDoc means less overhead on our SDK developers.

TypeScript users should get one module called `Apify` and from that access our SDK functions.

```js
import {Apify} from "apify";

const envs = Apify.getEnv();
...
```

This does not happen and the generated `index.d.ts` contains multiple modules, one for each JS source file.

---

## The situation

My JavaScript library is a single module visible to the client code. Source code is composed of multiple files in `src/` directory:

- `src/index.js`
- `src/actor.js`
- `src/request.js`
- ...

The `index.js` file re-exports functions defined in other files, so they can be accessed by client code running in Node.js.

```js
import { main, getEnv, call, callTask, ... } from './actor';
import Request from './request';
...

/**
 * The following section describes all functions and properties provided by the `apify` package...
 *
 * @module Apify
 */
module.exports = {
    main,
    getEnv,
    ...
    Request,
    ...
};
```

In `package.json`, the file `build/index.js` is defined as the entry-point (after being transpiled by babel from `src/index.js`):

```
{
   "main": "build/index.js",
   ...
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "noEmit": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "strict": false,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "outFile": "types/index.d.ts"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/index.js"
    ]
}
```

---

## Result

After running `tsc` I get my `types/index.d.ts`, with module declarations for each of my JS source file (each of them is inaccessible by the client code) and an empty `index` module:

```js
declare module "actor" {
    export function getEnv(): Env;
    export function main(userFunc: Function): void;
    ...
}
declare module "request" { ... }
...

declare module "index" {
    export {};
}
```

Comment: I'm adding a bounty to this question as I have run into this same issue, the question has a lot of views, and the current answer is unsatisfactory. A good answer will (imo) either: 1. Describe how to generate a proper declaration file when using this "re-export everything from index" style of module design, or 2. Describe the proper organizational structure for a typescript-based npm module and how to generate the declaration file under that design.

Answer (score 4):

this issue is because you are using `module.exports instead` of export `default`

change

```
/**
 * The following section describes all functions and properties provided by the `apify` package...
 *
 * @module Apify
 */
module.exports = {
    main,
    getEnv,
    ...
    Request,
    ...
};
```

to

```
/**
 * The following section describes all functions and properties provided by the `apify` package...
 *
 * @module Apify
 */
export default {
    main,
    getEnv,
    ...
    Request,
    ...
};
```

then for example lets look at this files

**actors.js**

```
module.exports = {
    main: () => { console.log("main") },
    getEnv: () => { console.log("getEnv") }
}
```

**request.js**

```
module.exports = {
    Request: () => { console.log("req") }
}
```

and **index.js**

```
import { main, getEnv } from './actor';
import Request from './request';

/**
 * The following section describes all functions and properties provided by the `apify` package...
 *
 * @module Apify
 */
export default {
    main,
    getEnv,
    Request,
};
```

types file with **module.export**

```
declare module "actor" {
    export function main(): void;
    export function getEnv(): void;
}
declare module "request" {
    export function Request(): void;
}
declare module "index" {
    export {};
}
```

and with `export default`

```
declare module "actor" {
    export function main(): void;
    export function getEnv(): void;
}
declare module "request" {
    export function Request(): void;
}
declare module "index" {
    namespace _default {
        export { main };
        export { getEnv };
        export { Request };
    }
    export default _default;
    import { main } from "actor";
    import { getEnv } from "actor";
    import Request from "request";
}
```

Comment: I don't really remember how we solved it, but the solution was similar to what you describe.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this on the index:

```js
export {main, getEnv} from './actor';
```